# Elasticsearch null_pointer_exception for non-null ArrayList

Tags: arrays, elasticsearch, nullpointerexception

I have a problem accessing values in the map given appropriate keys in Elasticsearch.

The query is as follows:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [ .... some conditions]
    }
  },
  "script_fields" : {
    "test1" : {
      "script": {
        "source": "ArrayList quotes = params._source.elements[0].somefield.parameters; def out = parameters; return out;",
        "lang": "painless"
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": [{"valueTosort": {"order": "asc"}}]
}
```

that returns

```
  "hits": [
  {
      "_index": "indexname",
      "_type": "data",
      "_id": "currentid",
      "_score": null,
      "fields": {
        "test1": [
          {
            "size": 10.1,
            "value": 0.0, 
            "additionalField": 1.0
          }
         ]
        },
        "sort": [
              1695827532254
          ]
      },
```

which is expected. However, as soon as I try to access the element of "parameters"

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [ .... some conditions]
    }
  },
  "script_fields" : {
    "test1" : {
      "script": {
        "source": "ArrayList quotes = params._source.elements[0].somefield.parameters; def out = parameters[0]; return out;",
        "lang": "painless"
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": [{"valueTosort": {"order": "asc"}}]
}
```

I get null_pointer_exception

```
                  "reason": {
                    "type": "script_exception",
                    "reason": "runtime error",
                    "script_stack": [
                        "out = parameters[0]; ",
                        "            ^---- HERE"
                    ],
                    "script": "ArrayList quotes = params._source.elements[0].somefield.parameters;  def out = parameters[0]; return out;",
                    "lang": "painless",
                    "position": {
                        "offset": 90,
                        "start": 78,
                        "end": 95
                    },
                    "caused_by": {
                        "type": "null_pointer_exception",
                        "reason": "Cannot invoke \"java.util.List.get(int)\" because \"<local3>\" is null"
                    }
                },
```

the same exception appears if the size of parameters is checked using .size() or .length

I have examined if the element was not null (comparing "parameters" to null) - it is not null, and inspected if "parameters" key existed using containsKey() as well as inspected the type of "parameters" (before assigning the value of params._source.elements[0].somefield.parameters to ArrayList) using "instance of".

Would you please advise what has to be done to access
"params._source.elements[0].somefield.parameters[0].additionalField" or "params._source.elements[0].somefield.parameters[0].value" (which clearly does not work)

Comment: Could you post the real output? This is not JSON `"test1": ["size": 10.1, "value": 0.0, "additionalField": 1.0}]`. Could you also format your queries a bit? It is very difficult to decipher what's going on there.

Comment: Apologies, somehow, I could not format the code as well as thank you for pointing the typo

Comment: I formatted it for you.

Comment: Which version of elasticsearch is this?

Comment: I tried reproduce this issue on v8.10.2 and I cannot. https://gist.github.com/imotov/265f02e3cc66603aade2c8dda0b86d8c Can you take a look at my example and modify it to fit your case?